# How to enable OpenGL 2.0 support on a Windows guest on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, steam

I am trying to run some games on Steam (specifically Dota 2 Reborn) on a Windows 7 64 bit guest under VirtualBox running on a Fedora Linux 23 64 bit host. I have enabled 2D and 3D acceleration on the machine settings and I have installed the guest additions with support for Direct 3D (I unchecked the "stable", basic version). But the game still won't run and complain about not having support for the minimun requirements:

> Missing basic OpenGL v1.0 -> v2.0 required OpenGL functionality.

[image]

My VM's settings are:

- 4 cores assigned
- 4096 MB RAM
- 256 MB video memory
- 3D acceleration enabled
- 2D acceleration enabled

How can I run this game with OpenGL support?

Comment: Does the virtual machine detect your GPU?  If it does have you installed the drivers for the GPU?  Based on the configuration you have provided for the virtual machine, with it only having 256 MB, I am going to guess that isn't the case.  You will have to use something other then Virtualbox to achieve your goals, the program, lacks the capability required to pass your GPU to the virtual machine.  Even if you solve the OpenGL problem, DOTA 2, requires more then 256 MB of video memory.