# How to enable OpenGL 2.x+ on Windows 7 guest on Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, opengl

This question has been asked before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1067131/how-to-enable-opengl-2-0-support-on-a-windows-guest-on-virtualbox#) but with no answers, so I'm going to ask it again.

How do I enable OpenGL version 2.x+ on VirtualBox? I've installed all guest additions. I'm on an Ubuntu 16.10 host.

Thanks!